# How to make QTextEdit handle standard shortcut commands with different keyboard language?

Tags: qt

I have an application which has QTextEdit widget. That widget is deeper in the hierarchy than another QWidget which has QAction with the shortcut QKeySequence::Copy.

Now, when the QTextEdit widget has the focus and my keyboard is set to English, everything works fine. The QTextEdit captures the shortcut and does what it's supposed to. However, if I change the language to "MKD" for example, then pressing "Ctrl+C" is no longer captured by the QTextEdit widget, but by the other widget. In fact, even if there is no "other" widget, the QTextEdit won't handle Ctrl+C.

I am not sure if I can do something about this, or maybe I am not doing something that I am supposed to for a case like this.

Comment: Which qt version are you using? Searching google for "qt shortcut language" yields a few pages on the issue tracker, some of which are closed in recent releases.

Comment: I am using 5.4.0 on Windows

Comment: Looks like it's Qt bug after all: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43596